# Subtracting the first row from all following rows

Tags: r, dplyr

From the following data set I want to subtract the values in the row labeled "BLK" from all subsequent rows (regardles of their lables).

```
 label   Int_A Int_B Int_C
 BLK     10    20    30    
 SMP     12.5  22.5  35    
 STD     15    25    40
```

Desired output:

```
 label   Int_A Int_B Int_C 
 BLK     10    20    30    
 SMP     2.5   2.5   5    
 STD     5     5     10
```

It does not matter if the BLK-row remains unchanged or will be set to zero.

Unfortunately, all answers I found consider only one variable, not all. I tried using the dplyr package, especially `rowwise()` and `transmute()` (there is no need to keep the old values) but failed also in calling an entire row and not only a certain variable. In basic R I also tried (and failed) but working with dplyr would be preferable, as the entire data set could exist of more than one of these sections and subsetting is easy with `group_by()` using a separate column.

I would be very glad if you could give me some advise or the required code.

Comment: Maybe `apply(df, 2, function(x) c(x[1], x[-1] - x[1]))`. (Untested.)

Comment: Similarly `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) c(x[1], x[-1] - x[1]))`, but then exclude non-numeric variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we need to subtract the `first` row from others, use `mutate_at` to specify the index of numeric columns or `mutate_if` and then subtract the `first` element from the all the elements of the column

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    mutate_at(2:4, funs(c(first(.), (. - first(.))[-1])) )
```

---

Or with `mutate_if`

```
df1 %>%
    mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(c(first(.), (. - first(.))[-1])) )
```

Comment: Based on your answer `df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(.-first(.)))` works perfectly.

Comment: This solution makes also first row zero.

Answer (score 3):

```
df[-1, -1] <- df[-1 , -1] - df[rep(1, nrow(df) - 1), -1]
df
#   label Int_A Int_B Int_C
# 1   BLK  10.0  20.0    30
# 2   SMP   2.5   2.5     5
# 3   STD   5.0   5.0    10
```

From relevant rows and columns `df[-1 , -1]`, subtract the first row `rep`eated to the necessary number of rows (`nrow(df) - 1`).

Comment: but but, where is `library(tibbliverse)`??

Comment: @DavidArenburg My `tiblificationaholicinizer` isn't working today...Stuck in the `base`ment. Plz hlp.

Comment: -1 for you have sinned. You should learn from [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8007738/hadley-is-my-hero) how to worship the true tibbliverseLord. Come back when you have reconsidered your actions.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I need to `explain` to you: My life is a `complete` mess. I am in deep `tribble`. No `funs` anymore. Should I `fill` my half-full glass? Get a `glimpse` of the unive..ehm..`tidyverse`? `separate` from my wife? Well, `n`o, how should I `explain` to her? She will `slice` me. Should I `join` `groups` of anonymous tibliholics `near` my `nest`? No, not the right `group_size` for me. For the `nth` time, `order_by` midnight for delivery next day! Why?! To `spread` my risks? I need to `pull` myself together, `expand` my views, and move on - rolling stones `gather` no moss!

Comment: Had Lee `mutate`d `lead` `band_members`? Just `between` you and me, they're `all_equal`: a `distinct`  feature is their compulsive preoccupation `with_order`. To `summarize`, this is _not_ a `case_when` we `unite` and `arrange` a `last` party. No, don't `do` it.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative using no packages:

`diff` is a matrix of the same size like df, with first row 0 and the rest equal to the 1st row in df. Then simply subtract.

```
df <- mtcars

diff <- matrix(c(rep(0,ncol(df)),rep(as.numeric(df[1,]),nrow(df)-1)),nrow=nrow(df),ncol=ncol(df),byrow=T)

df - diff
```